# Ensuring res.download() executes after another function has executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Express.js and HTML for this project about getting data, processing it, and writing it to a file that's downloaded right after clicking on the submit button in an HTML form.

`res.download()` within a post call executes and tries to download a file that hasn't been written to yet, and I'm trying to find out how I can cause `res.download()` to execute after data has been processed and is written to a file.

Here's the code:

```
let filtered = [], countEv = [];
let createdGTEDate = 0, createdLTEDate = 0;

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    getData();
    res.download('./filename.txt');
}

getData() {
    module.events.list(
    {
        limit: 100,
        types: ["charges"],
        created: {gte: createdGTEDate, lt: createdLTEDate}
    },
    function (err, events) {
        if(events !== null) {
            for (let i = 0; i < events.data.length; i++) {
                countEv.push(events.data[i]);
            }
            if (events.has_more) {
                recurringPaginate(events["data"][events["data"].length - 1].id);
            }
        }
    });

    function recurringPaginate(starting_after) {
        module.events.list(
            {
                limit: 100,
                created: {gte: createdGTEDate, lt: createdLTEDate},
                types: ["charge.succeeded", "charge.failed"],
                starting_after: starting_after
            },
            function (err, events) {
                for (let i = 0; i < events.data.length; i++) {
                    countEv.push(events.data[i]);
                }
                if (events.has_more) {
                    recurringPaginate(events["data"][events["data"].length - 1].id);
                }
                if(events.has_more === false) {
                    filterCharges();
                }
            });
    }
}

function filterCharges() {
    uniqueCharges = _.uniq(countEv, function (u) {
        return u.data.id;
    });
    pendingCharges = uniqueCharges.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.data.type === "pending";
    });
    writeCSV();
}

function writeCSV() {
    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("Report.csv");
    let writeData = "Start Date, End Date, Pending Charge Count \n" +
        createdGTEDate + ", " + createdLTEDate + ", " + pendingCharges.length + " \n";
    writeStream.write(writeData);
    writeStream.close();
}
```

Notes about the code:
- Using Underscore.js for the uniq() function.

The `getData()` function takes a while to complete execution as it needs to paginate through a lot of data, and every time the corresponding HTML form is submitted, the post call causes `res.download()` to execute right away and try to download the file, before `getData()` has even finished getting data.

Any ideas on what would be some good ways to ensure that all the data has been downloaded, processed and written to file before `res.download()` is actually causing the file to be downloaded?

**EDIT:** Added the missing bits of code above. Thanks all!

Comment: Have `getData` return a `Promise`

Comment: Please post the code from `getData()`

Comment: callbacks, events, promises, take your pick

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you for the hint! I haven't worked with Promises before, so I'll take a look into that

Comment: @Luca Thanks for your response, Luc. The code is specific to a Node API module from a payment service. It involves getting about 10 pages worth of paginated data (which takes upto 10 seconds), filtering the data to get unique charges and then writing them to a csv file.

Comment: @information_interchange Thanks for your response! I'll have to look into all of those options. Promises seem to be a good way to proceed here, and I've never worked with them before, so this will be a good learning experience.

Comment: If you want help figuring out how to include promises in this, please post the code of the function, you can leave out API-keys or things like that

Comment: @Luca I have added the remainder of the code in there. Please do let me know if you feel I'm missing any other information that anyone may need. Would appreciate any headstart I can get on how and where to use Promises!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question here, of course, after the hint regarding callbacks from @information_interchange in the comments, this was resolved by simply having a callback function for the write stream on close.

```js
.....
.....
writeStream.write(writeData); //write data to CSV write stream
    writeStream.close();
    writeStream.on("close", function() {  //callback function calls the download function when write stream has been closed
        downloadReport(res);
    })
.....
.....
```

Thanks everyone for your help and for any wandering souls who end up here, I hope all the responses here help you out!